How do you differentiate between fiction and reality?
It seems that once what was regarded as sci-fi and fiction becomes a reality in the future.
So how do you differentiate between what is real and what is virtual?
Since I can't.

Reality can be physical, social, mental. A movie is "real" when you see it on the screen and your bank account is only a string of bit in the electronic storage of a server. But you cannot pay bills with the money of the fiction, but neither with the paper money of Monopy game that are physially real.

@MauroALLEGRANZA virtual particles are real? what makes something real?

If you actually regularly cannot differentiate between fiction and reality in your day-to-day life, you need psychiatric help, not philosophy.

@JonathanZ Do you think you can reliably distinguish a text written by an AI as real or as fake without use of the internet?

Wait, you're saying some texts written by AI are real and some texts written by AI are fake?

@JonathanZ What do I know? I just asked ChatGPT to write a comment for me...

Heck, nobody actually writes anything anymore. We just push buttons and then some glowy dots appear on some screens.

Are the glowy dots conscious?

By not visiting a site where some take ideas like solipsism seriously

I'm sorry @MathematicalPhysicist, I don't understand the question. Please edit to give some examples of things in your experience which you know were scifi but now think are real, or real things which are now simulated.

@ScottRowe for example I once read that Jlues Varne envisdioned TVs some 150 years before they were a reality.

What is fictional one day may turn out to be fact when more information is available or circumstances change.
Any SF author will tell you that science fiction does not actually try to predict the future. Like philosophy, it is a what-if exercise; if these things which do not appear entirely impossible become possible in the future, what might some of the implications be. As such, science fiction is always in large part a reflection upon today, by metaphor, rather than really being about the future.
However, because SF does usually try to screen out the impossible (except for a few standard tropes such as FTL travel, or one or two hypotheticals introduced for purposes of the story), and since its authors try to be aware of the evolution of technology, occasionally it makes correct predictions. That happens more often when it is written by someone who has knowledge of that field, or when the prediction is an extension of a strong current trend. But it isn't the goal of the exercise.
But the proper term for fiction which has become fact is fact, and the proper term for fiction which may become fact in the future is speculative fiction. They really are different things.

Alexander's dictum, after Samuel Alexander (1920), states, that for something to be real it must have causal powers. It's a good start I think.
Of course, this is a philosophy forum, so you won't get much agreement of what is real and what is not real...

Right, we are still arguing over 'causal', 'powers', 'must', 'be', 'I', 'a' and so on. (we're pretty sure about e o and u)

@ScottRowe Are u?

I think that if we know we won't get much agreement, we should stop trying to.

@ScottRowe Sorry, it was a lame word joke... But on a more serious note, I think disagreement is important because it sets the boundaries. If you concede then you might end up with any truth. Maybe you don't care but they do. Then God is real and before you know it you end up in Gilead...

There is a very well established blueprint for distinguishing fact from fiction, namely the procedure followed in criminal courts. It requires a person with an open mind to consider all the available evidence and make a judgement based upon it. To reduce the fallibility of the process, you might  require the judgment of several open-minded people, as is the case with a jury. However, even then, it is possible to be duped if the fiction is artfully wrought to resemble reality.

Try this procedure on news (both Fox and CNN are reputable)

I never ever watch tv news or read newspapers.

Jury trial is a reasonable method for tough situations. I've asked the OP to give some examples for us to respond to.

It is a fundamental tenet of the majority of world religions that by and large:
We cannot distinguish!
A very clear cut example would be maya from Hindu philosophy. Usually maya is translated as illusion but it can also be read as the veil between the fiction and reality or the distorting lens that presents reality in fictionalized format.
More Examples

In Buddhism it's more indirect: the central focus is on dukha suffering. On examination it's found to rest on anicca (impermanence) and anatma (no-self). While impermanence is a characteristic of maya, no-self goes further and calls out the fact of the most foundational of all delusions — the delusion of an independent, autonomous self; ie. the arrogation to oneself of being-ness not merely contingent creature-ness.
Coming to philosophy, for Plato it has been said that all western philosophy is footnotes to Plato.
And perhaps his most significant and lasting contribution is The Allegory of the Cave with the (usual) world under illusion, chained in the cave and the (real) world outside.
Two millennia later Kant elaborated something similar when he articulated that what we see are phenomena; what really exists is noumena; and that there is no way to assume that the apparent phenomena will ever reveal the underlying noumena.
Gurdjieff has a sardonic description of the magician's sheep.
Even in Christianity, early Christian theology often regarded the material world as a temporary and imperfect reflection of divine reality. Concepts like the veil of the world suggest that earthly life is a shadow of the eternal truth of heaven.
Gnostic Christianity went even further emphasizing the material world as an illusion created by a lesser divine entity (the Demiurge), contrasting it with the transcendent truth of the spiritual realm beyond creation.
And most delightfully, Chuang Tzu describes a dream in which he was a butterfly and on waking cannot decide whether Chuang Tzu is dreaming of being a butterfly or the butterfly is dreaming of being Chuang Tzu.

All that said, it needs also be said that the adepts of all the above traditions tend to be intelligent, capable, cognizant folks; not maladjusted bums wandering inebriated.
To get that we need to understand the orders of reality in many eastern teachings. So for example in Vedanta there are three levels:


Pratibhasik Satya (Transitory Truth):
This refers to a subjective or illusory truth that is based on perception and individual experience. It encompasses phenomena that are real for an individual but not necessarily for everyone. For example, dreams or hallucinations fall under this category, as they have a reality for the person experiencing them but lack objective existence.
Vyavaharik Satya (Empirical Truth):
This represents the practical, everyday truth that is accepted and validated by society. It involves the truths that govern our interactions in the material world, such as the laws of physics, social norms, and shared experiences. Vyavaharik Satya is considered valid in a transactional sense but is still seen as limited and contingent upon the context of human experience.
Parmarthik Satya (Absolute Truth):
This is the ultimate, unchanging truth that transcends individual perception and empirical validation. Parmarthik Satya is often associated with spiritual enlightenment or the realization of the oneness of all existence. In Advaita Vedanta, this truth is identified with Brahman, the ultimate reality that is beyond the duality of existence.


Summary
So we may assume that the adepts are able to play by the rules of the empirical world, always knowing it as a game and a dream.

Mainstream Christianity does not present the world as illusory. It is often thought of as a broken world, but a very real world with real people and real consequences. It does discuss the concept that some of these real things exist to demonstrate non-physical things, but that doesn't imply that the real things are not real.

@DKing Yes. The words (adjectives) used in the Christianity paragraph are "temporary" "imperfect" "shadow" — "unreal", "illusion" are used elsewhere — and most critically Christianity itself is qualified as either early or gnostic, specifically so as to not include mainstream modern Christianity

Nonduality cuts to the chase by saying that our wonderful brains try to help by guessing about the future  (even the next second), but that is all they can do. So all of our ideas are actually guesses. So, figure on that being the case. Descartes attempted to go in that direction but somehow tied his shoelaces together, and we've been tripping over him on the stairs ever since.

Well, my friend... If you so choose to become that. I existed prior to the implementation of such technology into our lives. And the difference in the climate is undeniable. Everything is heavier. People are no longer people. I'm under constant pressures that have never-before been experienced because the weren't a component of the naturally evolving human condition. I can see things that aren't physically tangible. Just as well as I can hear them and oddly enough, feel them. So speaking in overall terms, life has gotten far worse as far as my life is concerned. That may not be true for other people. But those people had nothing to stand for to begin with. I prefer my natural existence, without this utterly unfair infringement on my life. Remember when I used to be able to get a job? And actually be good at that job? Well you've somehow made it a priority to not allow me to get a job. while other people are more than happy to do absolutely nothing, I happen to like being productive. And the essential property of living called "money" was a nice added touch too. Imagine that! Working to earn a paycheck... Absolutely baffling concept. So, yeah... Real life

I'm reading a book by Daniel Susskind called "A World Without Work" which covers the jobs aspect of your, post.
